# Permutation problem!

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I was recently trying to do an exercise that I am either misinterpreting or is wrong:

Show that each transposition $(k,k+1)$ is a product of $(1,2)$ and powers of
the $n$-cycle $(1,2,...,n)$.

I understood it as meaning that $(k,k+1) = (1,2,...,n)^m(1,2)$ or $(1,2)(1,2,...,n)^m$. However, I cannot make either work. For instance, for the symmetric group of four elements, I get $(2,1)$, $(3,2,4,1)$, $(4,3,1,2)$ and $(1,4,2,3)$ when I try the former. The latter does not give me a transposition either (except $(1,2)$). What am I doing wrong?

Also, in case you feel extra nice; How should I approach:

Show that each transposition $(i,j)$ is a product of transpositions of the form $(k,k+1)$.

Comment: induction will be worth trying

Comment: Try $(12\ldots n)^m(12)(12\ldots n)^k$.

Comment: Thank you alkabary and Jyrki Lahtonen! Induction seems to work on the second problem, and $(12…n)^m (12) (12…n)^k$ seems to be true for the 4-cycle, at least. Now, I just have to prove it for the n-cycle, and I am done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that $S_n = \langle (12) (12 \ldots n) \rangle$ for $n \geq 3$. Remember that $S_n = \langle \{\mathrm {transpositions}\}\rangle$. And notice that

$$(1\,2 \ldots n)(1\,2)(1\,2 \ldots n)^{-1} = (2\,3)\\(1\,2 \ldots n)(k-1\, k)(1\,2 \ldots n)^{-1} = (k\, k+1)$$

Comment: I know that every element in $S_n$ can be written as a product of transpositions. However, why can they be written as $\langle(12)(12..n) \rangle$. Isn't that every element of the form $\sigma = (12)(12..n)...(12)(12..n) = (12)(23)..(12)(23)$ or $(12)(23)..(23)(12)(12..n)$? Does permutations of this form really make up the whole of $S_n$?

Comment: Notice that $$(1\, 2 \, \ldots \, n) = (1n) (1\,n-1) \ldots \, (12)$$ then you have your first inclusion.

Comment: Now, remember $(1 \, 2 \, \ldots \, n)^{-1} = (n \, n-1 \, \ldots \ 1)$ and perform the first calculation to see why $2$ goes to $3$ and $3$ goes to $2$. By induction, this will give you the other inclusion.

Comment: Well, I have understood why every transposition of (k k+1) is sent to (k+1 k+2) by the conjugation above. However, now, I do not understand why that means that $\langle (12)(12..n)\rangle$ generates $S_n$.

Comment: I gave you the answer. In order to show that $A = B$ for two sets, you need to show two inclusions. Our case $$\langle (12) (12 \ldots n) \rangle \subset \langle \{\mathrm {transpositions}\}\rangle = S_n$$

Comment: And conversely. These two inclusions follow directly from what I have just told you in the comments above.

Comment: I have a nagging suspicion that the problem I have is that I do not know what ⟨(12)(12..n)⟩ is. In my mind, it is every permutation that can be written as $((12)(12..n))^n$ where n is an integer. I cannot see how every transposition can be written that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24504/discussion-between-aaron-maroja-and-avatrin).